# Compare two files with awk and map congregated multiple values

Tags: loops, csv, awk

I have two files I need to compare and map a value to which multiple rows match.

My mapping file (`map.csv`) looks like:

```
id,name
123,Hans
123,Britta
232,Peter
343,Siggi
343,Horst
```

The data file (`data.csv`) is

```
contact,id,names
m@a.de,123,
ad@23.com,343,
adf@er.org,123,
af@go.er,232,
llk@fh.com,343,
ad@wer.org,789,
```

The disired output should look like this

```
contact,id,names
m@a.de,123,Hans Britta 
ad@23.com,343,Siggi Horst 
adf@er.org,123,Hans Britta 
af@go.er,232,Peter 
llk@fh.com,343,Siggi Horst
ad@wer.org,789,NO ENTRY
```

There are multiple values for one ID in the mapping-file and they should be printed space-separated into the column `names` of the data-file. If there is no ID in the mapping file "NO ENTRY" should be printed instead.

This is the awk-command

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{print $0,($2 in a)? a[$2]:"NO ENTRY"}' map.csv data.csv
```

I clearly fail because I do not know how to loop through the mapping file for getting multiple values to one id (or currently any value at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] " ":"")$2
  next
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  sub(/,$/,"")
  print $0,($2 in arr)?arr[$2]:"NO ENTRY"
}
' map.csv data.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                          ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}
FNR==NR{                              ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when map.csv is being read.
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] " ":"")$2  ##Creating arr with index of $1 and which has value of $2 and keep concatenating its value with same index.
  next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==1{                               ##Checking condition if this is first line of data.csv then do following.
  print                               ##Printing current line here.
  next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  sub(/,$/,"")                        ##Substituting last comma with NULL here.
  print $0,($2 in arr)?arr[$2]:"NO ENTRY"  ##Printing current line and printing either value of arr with index of $2 OR printing NO ENTRY as per requirement.
}
' map.csv data.csv                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use two rules in your case. One to capture the data from `map.csv` and then a second rule to output the results, e.g.

(edit -- updated to match 1st row of output exactly)

```
awk -F, '
    NR==FNR { if (FNR > 1) a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2; next }
    FNR==1  { print; next }
            { printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, a[$2]?a[$2]:"NO ENTRY" }
' map.csv data.csv
```

The first rule is qualified by `NR=FNR` (current record number equal to the file record number -- e.g. the first file). The second rule is only run on the second file and outputs the heading row unchanged before outputting the aggregated data.

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply select-copy and middle-mouse-paste the command above into an xterm with the current directory holding `map.csv` and `data.csv` which results in the following:

```
$ awk -F, '
>     NR==FNR { if (FNR > 1) a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2; next }
>     FNR==1             { print; next }
>                        { printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, a[$2]?a[$2]:"NO ENTRY" }
> ' map.csv data.csv
contact,id,names
m@a.de,123, Hans Britta
ad@23.com,343, Siggi Horst
adf@er.org,123, Hans Britta
af@go.er,232, Peter
llk@fh.com,343, Siggi Horst
ad@wer.org,789,NO ENTRY
```

**Alternative**

An alternative that does the exact same thing, but simplifies (slightly) by explicitly setting `OFS=","` before output begins allowing the use of `print` instead of `printf` would be:

```
awk -F, '
    NR==FNR { if (FNR > 1) a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2; next }
    FNR==1  { OFS=","; print; next }
            { print $1, $2, a[$2]?a[$2]:"NO ENTRY" }
' map.csv data.csv
```

(same output)

Comment: both answers are great and give the correct result. I chose the other answer as solution, just because it was a little bit faster and explains the single steps of the awk-process.

Comment: No worries, good luck with your scripting. `awk` is a fantastic tool.